# [LARAVEL]¿Como puedo modificar y eliminar un registro de tablas muchos a muchos?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo dos problemas con laravel, estoy aprendiendo, pero la relacion muchos a muchos me ha dado muchas cuestiones.
Los problemas son el actualizar y el eliminar.
Me sale el error Missing required parameter for [Route: books.update] [URI: books/{book}] [Missing parameter: book]. al poner

```
    public function edit(Book $book, $id)
    {
        //
        $edits = Edit::all();
        $sagas = Saga::all();
        $states = State::all();
        $autors = Autor::pluck('name', 'id');
        $genres = Genre::pluck('name', 'id');
        $autors = Autor::all();
        $genres = Genre::all();

        

        return view('books.edit', compact('autors','genres','edits','sagas','states', 'book'));
        //return view('books.edit');
    }
```

Y es el que uso en las demas tablas y funciona bien, y menos se manejar el update...

```
     public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
    {
        //
        {
            $bok = $request->all();
            $book->update($bok);
            return redirect()->route('books.index');
       }
    }
```

Ahora, en eliminar, para esto se que debo borrar por id del registro de libro de la tabla pivot, pero no se como, en los tutoriales enseñan a registrar, pero no más

```
    {
        //
        $book = Book::find($id);
        $book->delete();

        return Redirect('/books');
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo leer [ask], el codigo NO debe ir en imagenes para eso hay herramientas de insercion de codigo cuando realizas tu pregunta, recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta

Comment: @David081 Gracias por la observación, soy nuevo en el sitio y la verdad no entendi al principio.